# Using lodash updatePosition not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, lodash

Hello So I am using `lodash` for the first time. My `jquery` code keeps jumping and I am trying to migrate it in the `lodash` function but I don't really understand how.

IDK if this matter but the main idea behind the code is for a div to scroll down to a position and snap to place but it keeps jumping. please advise !!

```
$(window).on('scroll', _.throttle(updatePosition, 100));

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    var sectionPosTop = document.getElementById('header-bamboo-scroll').getBoundingClientRect();

    var headerHeight = document.getElementById('header').getBoundingClientRect();


    if (scroll >= 660 && scroll <= 680 ) {
        console.log('greater than 660 and less than 680');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: headerHeight.height
         }, 500, function() {
            $('html, body').stop();
         });
    }

 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you want to do, but you can to use `_.throttle` to get a delay between code execution and that can give you a smooth animation. You can to adjust the delay time (in milliseconds) to get what you want.

```
    var updatePosition = function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      var sectionPosTop = document.getElementById('header-bamboo-scroll').getBoundingClientRect();

      var headerHeight = document.getElementById('header').getBoundingClientRect();


      if (scroll >= 660 && scroll <= 680 ) {
        console.log('greater than 660 and less than 680');
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: headerHeight.height
        }, 500, function() {
          $('html, body').stop();
        });
      }
    }

    $(window).on('scroll', _.throttle(updatePosition, 100));
```